# Incorrect Emacs access-label indentation for class with attribute

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

Emacs version info:

```
GNU Emacs 23.4.1
```

Emacs auto indentation of access-labels (i.e. public, private, protected) for a class that has an attribute seems broken.  Indentation is correct when the class does not have an attribute macro.

What should I add to my .emacs file (relevant lines below) to correct this problem?

Example of bad indentation:

```
#if defined(__linux__)
#  define SO_EXPORT  __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#elif defined(WIN32)
#  define SO_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

class SO_EXPORT MyClass
   : public MyBaseClass
{
 public:                 // <--- BAD: a leading space!               
   MyClass();            // <--- correct, indentation is set to 3 spaces                                                                  
   virtual ~MyClass();
 private:                // <--- again with the space!                                                                                    
   int m_myVariable;
};
```

Here are the results of running 'c-show-syntatic-information' on the above snippet:

- with macro:         ((label 206))
- NO macro: ((inclass 196) (access-label 196))

Here are the relevant settings from my .emacs file:

```lisp
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (setq fill-column 130)
  (setq c-basic-offset 3)
  (local-set-key "\C-m" 'c-context-line-break)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open '0)
  (c-set-offset 'case-label '+)
  (c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty '++)
  (c-set-offset 'brace-list-open '0)
  (c-set-offset 'brace-list-open '0)
  (c-set-offset 'innamespace '0)

  (setq lazy-lock-defer-contextually t)
  (setq lazy-lock-defer-time 0)
  )
```

Comment: Use `clang-format`. MELPA has the `.el`. You will need to install the binary on your own.

Comment: @Pradhan, `clang-format` is interesting, but I'd rather fix my `.emacs` file than install binary extras.